# WCF long running process

Tags: c#, wcf

I've to launch a long running process using a WCF service, for now I don't need a result, but I could need it soon, so suppose both scenario, execute an action of a function.

I tried different approaches:

1. the server is synchronous, the client makes a sync call using another process that stay alive
2. the server is synchronous, the client make an async call using the same process that could be closed
3. the server is async, the client makes a sync call using the same process

If the client closes the communication with the server, the server kills the execution so it does not complete the task?

Which is the best way to avoid this scenario?

Is a good thing to execute the code in the server using the Task class?

Comment: Avoid what scenario?  Do you want the server to stop execution if the client disconnects or not?

Comment: I want to continue the task anyway

Answer (score 0):

A solution can be use the [IsOneWay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontractattribute.isoneway.aspx) property in the OperationContractAttribute.

Answer (score -1):

I dont think WCF Is the solution for you here, In WCF once the connection is closed the remote procedure is considered failed and thus terminated.

I would suggest you went for a different approach, try implementing a client-server request-respond type of communication, which seems a better fit in the case you are discribing, though if you would state the scenario for which you are using the server it would offer better help.